# jQuery works except one piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

My whole JS file works except this piece of code:

```
    //Accordion
jQuery('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
    console.log(jQuery("#accordion").find(".accordion-toggle"))

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

});
```

If I put this in the browser console it works fine.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It is even executing? Is there an error being thrown? Please be a little more articulate on what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: No error, I looks like it is not recognized

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: From what you describe it sounds like either interfering code from something else on your page or the elements just don't exist yet. The DOM ready function will fix the latter issue so at least rule that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a DOM ready function:

```
$(function() {
    //Accordion
    jQuery('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
        console.log(jQuery("#accordion").find(".accordion-toggle"));

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    }); 
});
```

Comment: @Tiboon Great please can you accept this as the answer

Comment: Needed to wait 10 minutes before that could be done ^^